# AB = I and BC = I then what is the relation between A and C?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

B = matrix given below. I is identity matrix.

```
 [1 2 3 4]
 [3 2 4 3]
 [1 3 2 4]
 [5 4 3 7]
```

So What will be the relation between the matrices A and C if AB = I and BC = I?

I think that A = C because both AB and BC have B in common and both of their product is an identity matrix but I'm not sure.

Comment: Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?

Comment: What possibilities do you have to express B?

Comment: In the title - why do you need a matrix $C$ ? If $AB=I$, then the relation between $A$ and $B$ is just $A=B^{-1}$, or $B=A^{-1}$.

Comment: So sorry about the mistakes i made in the question! I was actually in a hurry so didn't quite gave it a thorough look. Thank you for letting me know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose $AB=I$ and $BC=I$; then
$$
A=AI=A(BC)=(AB)C=IC=C
$$

Comment: That really helps! Now if i want to find the inverse of matrix A (or C), it would simply be inverse of B right?

Comment: @NisargPatel Yes, of course: an interesting result is that if a square matrix $B$ has a left inverse $A$, *then* also $BA=I$ (which is not obvious).

Answer (score 0):

If $AB=I$, then $B$ is invertible and possesses a unique inverse, and clearly, this can only be the matrix $A$. Hence
$$
AB=I\qquad\Longrightarrow\qquad AB=BA=I.
$$
Likewise, if $BC=I$, then $C$ is the inverse of $B$, the *unique inverse*, and therefore
$A=C$.

Answer (score 0):

$B$ is invertible.
Since $AB=I$, $A=IB^{-1}$,
and since $BC=I$, $C=B^{-1}I$.
Therefore $A = C$.

Answer (score -2):

Hint : Multiply $AB=I$ from right with $B^{-1}$ and $BC=I$ from left with $B^{-1}$. What do you get ?

Comment: Note that $B^{-1}$ exists because of $AB=I$.

Comment: Technically more is required to establish $B^{-1}$ as both a left and right inverse that is unique as a left inverse and unique as a right inverse if this is to be solved from "first principles".

Comment: @Peter We do know that $\det(B)=45$. So $B$ will be invertible, if the field has characteristic different from $3$ or $5$.